# Dart, how does noSuchMethod work with mixins?

Tags: dart, mixins

I'm experimenting with this idea:

```dart
void main(){
  var actual = new Actual();
  actual.notImplemented(); //I'd like it to print A, B C,
}

class A{
  void noSuchMethod(Invocation inv){
    print('A');
  }
}

class B{
  void noSuchMethod(Invocation inv){
    print('B');
  }
}

class C{
  void noSuchMethod(Invocation inv){
    print('C');
  }
}

class Actual extends Object with A, B, C{}
```

at the moment this prints out "C" but I understand that you cannot make calls to `super` in mixin classes, does anyone know why the behavior of mixins is like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a mixin application with multiple mixins, like `with A, B, C`, they are applied in order. That means that the superclass of `Object with A, B, C` is `Object with A, B`, and the `noSuchMethod` of `C` is overriding the ones mixed in from `A` and `B`.